# AppendTo(<script></script>) não executa o script adicionado

Tags: jquery, script, append

Estou criando um light box para que é executado com base no clique em um link.

O light box funciona normalmente e consigo adicionar conteúdo dentro dele sem problemas. A questão é que nesse em específico preciso adicionar um javascript que puxa um de meus formulários.

O javascript até é impresso dentro da DIV mas o navegador não executa ele. Alguém sabe me dizer o que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Segue o código que estou usando abaixo.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  function createLightBoxForm() {
    var linkForm = $('.pega-form').attr('value');
    var bgLight = $('<div class="bg-lightbox"></div>');
    var colorLight = $('<div class="color-lightbox"></div>').appendTo(bgLight);
    var contLight = $('<div class="cont-lightbox"></div>').appendTo(bgLight);
    var closeLight = $('<a class="close-btn-lightbox" href="#">X</a>').appendTo(contLight);
    var formLight = $('<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.secnet.com.br/form/generate.js?id=' + linkForm + '"><\/script>').appendTo(contLight);
    bgLight.appendTo('body');
  }
  $('body').on('click', '.ltbox-call', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   createLightBoxForm();
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.close-btn-lightbox', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.bg-lightbox').remove();
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.color-lightbox', function() {
    $('.bg-lightbox').remove();
  });
});
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Luan, quero te ajudar mas você forneceu pouca informação para entender a origem do problema. Mas de modo superficial poderia dizer que vc está tendo problemas em acessar o script carregado dinamicamente, devido à questão de ordem no caso, o script que é "appended" deve estar pronto para ser usado, no caso veja se tal script possuí algum método "load" para ser executado apos ser carregado. ou forneça mais informação para poder te ajudar

Comment: Fala Vinicius, agora que você comentou sobre o load já me deu uma luz, vou verificar isso certinho e se ainda assim não conseguir, eu trago mais informações para você. Muuito obrigado!